# How do I add repository to Android and what repositories do I add to get xrdp?

Tags: terminal

I'm using [Termux](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.termux). What do I type in my Terminal on Android to add a new repository in order to install more applications into my terminal?

I'm using Android 5, ZTE Blade S7 if that helps.

Comment: Unless you tell me what terminal program comes with repositories, I cannot help you much. The only one I'm aware of is *Termux* – but I never heard there are multiple repositories behind it. Don't forget, you're not on Linux here, though Android uses a (modified) Linux kernel :)

Comment: I'm using Termux.  I guess I can't add repositories.  :(

Comment: That's at least a detail :) I never heard there were additional repositories to *Termux* except for the one maintained by its dev. Its help page on [package management](https://termux.com/package-management.html) doesn't mention anything alike. You could, however, check the [project site](https://github.com/termux/termux-app), especially the issues, if there was already a notion and, if not, open an issue to ask.